# Drop spaces from end and begin only in all list elements

Tags: python, regex, list

I have list `my_list`

`my_list = [' Cat Alfred ', ' Dog Austin Power ', ' Very very very lazy frog ']`

I need to delete all space at beginning and end and allow spaces between characters to have output:

`['Cat Alfred', 'Dog Austin Power', 'Very very very lazy frog']`

I have tried to use:

```
pattern = r"[^\w]"
names_only_words = [(re.sub(pattern, "", name)) for name in my_list]
```

But this will delete spaces between characters as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could be done simply using a list comprehension, avoiding the need to use regex.

```
names_only_words = [x.strip() for x in my_list]
```

Will strip spaces from the ends of the strings but not the middle:

```
['Cat Alfred', 'Dog Austin Power', 'Very very very lazy frog']
```

If you did want specifically to do it with regex, the following would work:

```
pattern = "^\s*(.*?)\s*$"
names_only_words = [(re.match(pattern, name).group(1)) for name in my_list]
```

Rather than the original approach of replacing the spaces at the ends with nothing, it captures everything between the spaces at the ends.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a map with strip function:

```
names_only_words = list(map(lambda x: x.strip(),my_list))
```

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_strip.htm

```
['Cat Alfred', 'Dog Austin Power', 'Very very very lazy frog']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this too:

```
list(map(str.strip, my_list))
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use a for loop and the strip() method from the `str` class:

```
for text in my_list:
    text = text.strip()  # removes spaces before and after text
```

Comment: As written, this doesn't produce the required list.